# Formula help for writing an IF statement or formula, base upon a value selected from a drop-down list in googlesheets

Tags: validation, if-statement, drop-down-menu, google-sheets-formula

I have a column with a data validation drop-down list, for multiple product types. For the sake of illustrating my scenario. I will say in Column B, Row 4.

I am trying to write a formula in an adjacent column (Column C), Row 4. Where if the drop-down cell in column b, is a certain value from the list, then in column C it will be filled with a prefix which is correspondant to the particular value chosen from the drop-down menu.

Example. I have a drop-down list with 6 values. One of my drop-down list values is "Raw Material". When raw materials is chosen from the drop-down list, i want column c, row 4 value to display the prefix Q-RwM.
I have a seperate table of the drop-down statements and their associated prefixes, but i am so far unable to write a successful formula or data validation which will deliver the aim i am trying to achieve.

Can anyone help me?

I have tried Arrayformulas. IF and IFS statements. I have tried putting the IF statements into the custom formula within the data validation function.
All currently have displayed error when completed.